# How does one distinguish between VB5 and VB6 projects?

Tags: vb6, vb5

I have to maintain a number of minor legacy apps and most of them have no or minimal documentation.  There are a couple of these which were written either in VB5 or 6, but I can't tell which.  There doesn't seem to be big difference in the appearance of the source code, and I can load either one using VB6, and even run them in the IDE, but I have the feeling that the older of the two is VB5.  Is there a way to tell by code inspection which one a project was created in?  Or some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .VBP file for a VB6 project will contain a line like this:

```
Retained=0
```

VB5 project files do not contain this line. You can load VB6 project files in VB5, but you get a warning about the invalid "Retained" key.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the project file.

Also, if you have had both installed, when you OPEN the project file from Explorer, it should start the "VB Selector" tool that will figure out which version to open for that project.